# how to send bubble message in android

Tags: java, android

[image]

I am using a custom list adapter...to display message i want change it to bubble message...
`this.ListAdapter = new IndMessageAdapter(this,
                R.layout.chatmessage_list,
                Messages);`

---

Criteria s:

1.Bubble should expand according the message length...

2.bubble not shrink or....change it resolution??

any idea how to proceed??

---

Answer (score 0):

Use `TextView` and set this image as `background image`

**Example**

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/messagescreenrow_senderChatText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ok"
            android:background="@drawable/groupbubble"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:paddingRight="10dip"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
            />
```

Comment: i have done but image resolution goes off...if typyin bigger message...and bubble image covers the list`
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  
 <TextView android:id="@+id/messagelisting" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:textColor="#000000"
  android:paddingLeft="2dp"
  android:paddingTop="2dp" 
  android:textSize="16dip"
  android:background="@drawable/bubble_right"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@id/messagelisting"/>

</RelativeLayout>`

Comment: yes the image resolution will go because we have set it as background. you can do one more thing you can get the width if textview here and resize image width and set the image programmetically using textView.setBackgroundDrawable method